# MySQL: Get direct siblings of the row

Tags: mysql, siblings

I have problem to select direct siblings of the main row. For example this is my data I need to filter:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | from       | to         |
+------+------------+------------+
| 2265 | 2016-03-30 | 2016-04-09 |
| 1420 | 2016-03-30 | 2016-04-11 |
| 2261 | 2016-03-30 | 2016-04-12 |
| 2262 | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-12 |
| 1296 | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-24 |
| 1053 | 2016-04-01 | 2016-05-01 |
| 2302 | 2016-04-30 | 2016-05-24 |
| 2025 | 2016-05-14 | 2016-06-06 |
| 2392 | 2016-05-20 | 2016-05-28 |
| 2033 | 2016-05-21 | 2016-06-08 |
| 2389 | 2016-05-25 | 2016-06-09 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

All I need is to select row and it's direct siblings by min/max dates. For example, result should be:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | from       | to         |
+------+------------+------------+
| 1296 | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-24 |
| 1053 | 2016-04-01 | 2016-05-01 |
| 2302 | 2016-04-30 | 2016-05-24 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

Where row `1053` is the "main" row.

I know it's something with `MIN` and `MAX` functions, but I can't figure how to use it. I could do it in my app, but I'd rather do it in SQL because of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want something like the following query:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mytable AS m
JOIN (
  SELECT id, 
         (SELECT id 
          FROM mytable AS t2
          WHERE t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.`to` >= t2.`to`
          ORDER BY `to` DESC, `from` DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev_id,
         (SELECT id 
          FROM mytable AS t3
          WHERE t1.id <> t3.id AND t1.`to` <= t3.`to`
          ORDER BY `to`, `from` LIMIT 1) AS next_id        
  FROM mytable AS t1
  WHERE id = 1053
) AS t ON m.id IN (t.id, t.prev_id, t.next_id)
```

The above query uses two correlated subqueries in order to get *previous* and *next* records with regard to the record having the specified `id` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d83/5)

Comment: I think you are correct, but I need to test it. There is one record with ``to`` value less than previous row, but it's below because of ``from`` date.  So I guess I should omit ``to`` value as long as ``from`` is different.

Comment: Don't know how to edit comments, so I'll post another.. I did a little update to your answer with conditional statement and querying by ``from`` value which is more important than ``to``. [Edited demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d83/23)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method utilizing `user variable`.

```
select t1.id, t1.from, t1.to
from 
    (select *, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as row_num from t 
        cross join (select @rn1 := 0) p1) t1
    cross join (select @target := 
        (select t2.row_num 
        from (select *, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as row_num from t 
            cross join (select @rn2 := 0) p2) t2
        where t2.id = 1053)
    ) p3
where t1.row_num in (@target-1, @target, @target+1);
```

To use it on your table, replace `t` to your own table name.